# NavigationView Extra Space at Top

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've added a NavigationBar to my share extension. When the NavigationView is added an extra space appears the top (image below).

Other answers have suggested to remove the NavigationView.. without it the NavigationView the bar does not show.

How can I remove this space while keeping the NavigationBar?

```swift
class ShareViewController: UIViewController {    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white

        let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: TempView())

        self.addChild(vc)
        self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
        vc.didMove(toParent: self)
        vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        vc.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        vc.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        vc.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        vc.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        vc.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        vc.view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear        
    }
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TempView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Ok")
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
            .navigationBarItems(
              leading:
                Text("Close"),
              trailing:
                Text("Next")
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Extra Navigation Bar Space]

Comment: If you use SwiftUI NavigationView you should not set UINavigationBar via UIKit, they are not combined. Instead either use only NavigationView or try to modify UINavigationBar.appearance() before showing NavigationView.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for the quick response. Interesting, if I clear the viewWillAppear and add in navigationController?.navigationBar.height = true then the SwiftUI NavigationView bar appropriately doesn't have the space. However, if I link to another view then the bar unfortunately does not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I mismatch my reading, you are trying to use swiftui in an extension? I'll recommend going with ViewControllers. Anyway try removing the navigation view

```
struct TempView : View {

var body: some View {
    // NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Text("Ok")
            Spacer()
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        .navigationBarItems(
          leading:
            Text("Close"),
          trailing:
            Text("Next")
        )
    }
// }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting, if you take out the NavigationView the bar does not show..

Comment: Because you're adding two. One is your first navigation controller which you configure in your viewWillAppear, and the other one is the Navigation Controller in the navigation view. I'll suggest you add the functionality of the Close and Next buttons in the View Controller, please read this link, and if you succeed give me a valid answer. https://diamantidis.github.io/2020/01/11/share-extension-custom-ui

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'd like to try to figure out how to do this with SwiftUI. I comment out the viewWillAppear configuration a space still appears like this: https://imgur.com/a/31xVBem

Comment: I'm not sure if I am making my point. You're adding 2 Navigation Controllers to your view, one is the one on View Controller and the other is the Navigation View. You're only configuring it in viewWillAppear.

Comment: Thanks again for clarifying and sharing that link. I'll mark yours answered as it works. For others, my solution that works for now was to hide the UIKit Navigation Bar and then use SwiftUI NavigationView and default NavigationLink (i.e. without the programatic selection and EmptyView() implementation)